# Liberar link após preenchimento de formulário

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sou iniciante em `Javascript/jQuery` e estou com dúvida de como fazer para liberar um link logo após todos inputs estiverem preenchidos, caso contrário ele se mantém bloqueado:

Segue HTML:

```
<form id="formulario">
    <label>Usuário</label>
    <input id="usuario"> 
    <label>Senha</label>
    <input id="senha">
    <button type="button" id="login">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível resolver seu problema apenas com um atributo HTML5 chamado `required`.

```
<form id="formulario" action="http://meusite.com.br">
    <label>Usuário</label>
    <input id="usuario" required> 
    <label>Senha</label>
    <input id="senha" required>
    <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login">
</form>
```

Dessa forma o browser faz a validação verificando se campo obrigatório está preenchido.

Comment: lembrando que o required é um atributo novo do HTML5

Comment: Não faltou @WallaceMaxters, quem faz esse trabalho é o *browser*, enquanto o formulário não for válido o `submit` não vai enviar e o *browser* vai solicitar que os campo sejam preenchidos, ou seja, o submit fica desabilitado.

Comment: e onde iria o link neste caso, @Erlon Charles? Creio ser isso que o Wallace quis dizer...

Comment: No action do Form, vou editar e colocar uma url falsa

Comment: @WallaceMaxters acho que você ta implicando com pouca coisa velho kkk o atributo Required do HTML5 serve justamente para o mesmo proposito.... So existem "dois problemas" ao usar o required.... primeiro se a requisição for feita em Ajax, segundo se o browser do usuário não suportar as tags de HTML5, coisa que hoje é pouco provável.

Comment: Só há problema em usar o ajax no formulário se você colocar a ação dele no `.click`. Se você usar o `$("form").submit` a ação só será enviada quando o form estiver válido. Eu já fiz isso várias vezes

Comment: Sem problemas @WallaceMaxters, é a mesma pergunta interpretada de duas formas diferentes, no fim das contas o que importa é mostrar formas diferentes de se resolver o mesmo problema, uma resposta inteiramente completa teria todas as soluções possíveis para este problema. A sua resposta não esta errada e nem a minha, as duas são complementares já que se você tiver um formulário bem formatado a funcionalidade vai ser a mesma que fazendo a validação por javascript e ativando/mostrando um link apenas com um form válido.

Comment: Agora se, o caso for usabilidade e não apenas a funcionalidade (o que não ficou claro na pergunta) é um caso diferente.

Comment: Para mitigar a intenção do usuário de clicar em um botão com um formulário não completo ainda o ideal era que o botão fosse mostrado apenas depois de todo formulário ter sido preenchido corretamente, fazendo a validação a cada `focus` ou a cada `keyup`.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o *bootstrapValidator*. É simples e fica muito bom visualmente

```
$('#formulario').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'O valor informado não é válido!"',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'fa fa-check-circle fa-lg text-success',
            invalid: 'fa fa-times-circle fa-lg',
            validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            usuario: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Preencha o usuário antes de continuar!'
                    }
                }
            },
            senha: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Preencha a senha antes de continuar!'
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    }).on('success.field.bv', function(e, data) {
        var $parent = data.element.parents('.form-group');
        $parent.removeClass('has-success');+ '"]').hide();
    }).on('error.form.bv', function(e) {
        isValid = false;
    });
```

Se por acaso o usuário clicar em login antes de preencher os campo, o botão é desabilitado a as mensagens que foram setadas na função serão mostradas em baixo do input.

Comment: +1 Não conhecia! Parece ser interessante

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi direito que você quer liberar um link sendo liberado após os dados preenchidos, faça o seguinte. Altere seu HTML para:

```
<form id="formulario">
    <label>Usuário</label>
    <input required id="usuario"> 
    <label>Senha</label>
    <input id="senha" required>
    <button type="button" id="login">Login</button>
</form> 

<a id="seu_link" class="disabled">Seu link Bloqueado</a>
```

E, com o `jQuery`, faça o seguinte:

```
$(function(){

    $('#login').click(function(e){


       if ($("#usuario").is(':valid') && $("#senha").is(':valid')) {
           // Ação ao submter o formulário 
           $("#seu_link").removeClass('disabled');
       } else {
          e.preventDefault();
       }
    });


   $(document).on('.disabled', 'click', function(){ return false; });

});
```

Assim você está verificando se o input está preenchido.

**Nota**: A verificação com `is(':valid')` ou `is(':invalid')` só é possível se o input possuir o atributo `required` ou o `pattern`.

Segue o exemplo do [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxz8wwwL/)

No caso, como imaginei que talvez você, ao invés de querer desbloquear um link, desbloquear o botão que faz o `submit`.

Então elaborei o seguinte código.

Formulário:

```
<form id="formulario">
    <label>Usuário</label>
    <input required id="usuario"> 
    <label>Senha</label>
    <input id="senha" required>
    <button type="button" id="login" disabled>Login</button>
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){

    var $btn = $("#login");

    $("#usuario, #senha").on('keyup', function(){
        if ($('#usuario').is(':valid') && $('#senha').is(':valid')) {
            $btn.attr({disabled:false});
        } else { 
            $btn.attr({disabled: true});
        }
    });

});
```

Você pode ver esse segundo exemplo nesse [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxz8wwwL/)
Penso que dessa segunda forma, a usabilidade é maior

Comment: Você esqueceu de colocar a classe `disabled` no link que ficará desabilitado.

Comment: rsrsrs, valeu @ErlonCharles

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, poderia colocar um exemplo no jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias formas de se fazer isso Éder...
Uma delas é usando uma biblioteca chamada **`Jquery-Validate`**, existe tbm uma outra biblioteca que eu gosto que se chama **`validationEngine`**

Na mão, utilizando apenas recursos do JQuery você pode fazer algo do tipo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").click(function(e){
     // bloqueando envio do form
     e.preventDefault();
     var erros = 0;
     // verifica se ha campos vazios
     $("#formulario input").each(function(){
      // conta erros
      $(this).val() == "" ? erros++ : "";
     });
     if(erros > 0 ){  
      alert("Existe "+erros+" campo(os) vazio neste fomulário");
        }else{
      $("#formulario").submit()
     }    
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="formulario">
<label>Usuário</label>
<input id="usuario"> 
<label>Senha</label>
<input id="senha">
<input type="button" id="login" value="Login">
</form>
```